# Why does validation work on form names rather than on the model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="accountForm">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': accountForm.CurrentPassword.$invalid  }">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Current Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="CurrentPassword" ng-model="user.CurrentPassword" ng-minlength="8" placeholder="Enter current password">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Why do we have to give the form and input fields a name, and perform validation on that, is there a way to use ng-model directly? It would be so much cleaner if we could do:

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': user.CurrentPassword.$invalid  }">
```

Don't take it in the context of one field, but in the context of a form with dozens of fields. It starts to get old very quickly. It seems to me that

```
<input name="CurrentPassword" ng-model="user.CurrentPassword"/>
```

is redundant (even though I understand that there is different functionality involved and one is coming from the traditional HTML post methodology). However, I am posting my model in Angular so I don't need that functionality, but I'm forced to add it anyway due to validation?

**Edit:**

Yes, of course modifying the class and/or using `disabled=""` based on the model is also an option but results in very ugly HTML and obviously `$touched`, `$invalid` and `$error` would not work... any other options? Or can anyone explain if there's any valid reasoning why it was written in this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the AngularJS form validation you have to use it as you did.
Otherwise you can do your own rules based on model binding, for example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="accountForm">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (user.CurrentPassword.length < 8)  }">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Current Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="CurrentPassword" ng-model="user.CurrentPassword" placeholder="Enter current password">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Of course not, if you don't use the `ng-` method for validation it can't work

Comment: I'm looking for a clean way to perform validation without using the `name=""` attribute. Seems like I have to write a custom directive or something